# Oracle DB loadjava error (ORA-29509): incorrectly formed Java binary class definition

Tags: java, oracle, log4j, oracle19c

I'm trying to import an external library (`log4j-api` version `2.21.0`) to the database but I get the following error:

```
CALL dbms_java.loadjava('-resolve -force -debug -fileout /home/usr/out.txt -verbose /home/usr/log4j-api-2.21.0.jar')
Error report -
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: oracle.aurora.rdbms.MalformedDefinitionException: In ClassHandle.create in schema USRSCHEMA

ORA-29509: incorrectly formed Java binary class definition
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JAVA", line 587
ORA-06512: at line 1
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

with `usr` and `USRSCHEMA` being placeholders. I am using Oracle Database 19c and DBMS Java JDK version `1.8.0_201`. The `loadjava` command is:

`CALL dbms_java.loadjava('-resolve -force -debug -fileout /home/usr/out.txt -verbose /home/usr/log4j-api-2.21.0.jar')`

Stack trace does not provide additional details nor does `out.txt` and `USER_ERRORS` table. Obviously, being an apache commons library, it should have no issues with compiling and compatibility. Namely, the major version is 52 and the library worked when I tried it out seperately in a locally compiled project. I downloaded the latest version of the jar from the [jar-download website](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api) and it has no dependencies. To verify, I also downloaded other apache libraries and even `gson`, which were loaded into the database without issue. Their major versions varied from 49-52 so this isn't the problem I believe.

However, if I tried an earlier version of `log4j-api`, it gave me a different error related to resolving. Interestingly, the newest version that gave me this different error is `log-4j-api` version `2.9.1`, which released a few days before Java 9. The earliest version of `log-4j-api` (version `2.0`) loads into the database without problem.

What might be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `/home/usr/log4j-api-2.21.0.jar` a path on the SQL server machine?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes. I have permissions to access it as well (both from the OS and the DB). If I did not, I would be getting a different error.